# .gitignore file showing up in git status under untracked files

Tags: git

Git newbie here. I am probably making a simple mistake here, but I can't seem get my .user files to disappear from the git status output under untracked files. When you add a file to the .gitignore file, it should not show up at all in "git status" right? Here is my .gitignore file:

```
.*.suo
.*.user
```

I have also tried it like this: `.*\.user`
The file that is showing up under the git status is ACS.CF/ACS.CF.UI.Framework/ACS.CF.UI.Framework.csproj.user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

*.suo

*.user

Comment: That worked, thanks. Could you explain this? Did I just make a regular expression mistake?

Comment: @INTPnerd: They're not regexes, they're globs.

Comment: I hate it when I don't realize I'm making an assumption. Thanks.